# Incomplete decryption C++ and WCHAR

Tags: c++, encryption

Writing a module for encryption and decryption of WCHAR in C++

```
static UINT OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE = 22;
static int oglKeyTable[] = { 10, 71, 45, 13, 16, 19, 49, 55, 78, 125, 325, 
10, 71, 45, 13, 16, 19, 49, 55, 78, 125, 325 };
PCWSTR encryptString(PCWSTR Message)
{
    int size = lstrlenW(Message);
    WCHAR Encrypted[200];
    for (wchar_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (((Message[i] + oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]) <= 255)
            &&
            ((Message[i] + oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]) != 0)
            )
            Encrypted[i] = (Message[i] + oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]);
        else
            Encrypted[i] = Message[i];
    }
    Encrypted[size]= '\0';
    int Esize = lstrlenW(Encrypted);
    printf("\n%ls", Message);
    printf("\n%ls", Encrypted);
    size = lstrlenW(Encrypted);
    WCHAR Decrypted[200];
    for (wchar_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (Encrypted[i] <= 255 ) {
            Decrypted[i] = (Encrypted[i] - oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]);
        }
    }
    Decrypted[size] = '\0';
    printf("\n%ls", Decrypted);
    return Encrypted;
}
```

But the logic is failing somewhere and I am getting incomplete decryption

- Original message  : `Apple tastes good and it__is__very__good__for
  health !`
- Encrypted message : `K+¥yu3Ñÿ-±e}gö|¦wQÿ+ß
  s+îlyåÉû-Grâªît¦éòû¡po|gòrq¦ÑƒnP`
- Decrypted messsage: Apple tast

Comment: I think you want to use e.g. `L'\0'` for the terminator character.

Comment: Also, the type of your loop variable `i` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thirdly, do you get the truncated text when you print inside the `encryptString` function, or when you print from somewhere else?

Comment: Lastly, `stdout` (which is used by `printf`) is by default line-buffered, which means it will flush the output buffers on newline. Printing a newline *before* the actual output makes no sense, as then the actual output won't be printed until the next newline which can happen far away, or not at all. *End* your output with a newline instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some serious problems with your cipher. You only permit ciphertext values in the range of [1, 255], yet two times the key component of 325 is used which is then added to the plaintext. During encryption you then decide in those cases that the plaintext char is also the ciphertext char. But then during decryption you don't distinguish between the two branches of encryption.

```
WCHAR Decrypted[200];
for (wchar_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ((Encrypted[i] - oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]) > 0) {
        Decrypted[i] = (Encrypted[i] - oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]);
    } else {
        Decrypted[i] = Encrypted[i];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work for every key component, but this is the correct reason of the problem, because you get negative chars during decryption. The first char this is missing is at `i == 10` which is consistent with the 325 key component.

A better way would be to keep the key and use a modulo operator to stay in the correct range:

```
Encrypted[i] = ((Message[i] + oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]) % 255) + 1;
```

and the equivalent reverse of this during decryption. If you do this, you won't need the two branches anymore. It has some similarities to the Vigenère cipher.

---

Old solution:

<strike>The problem is that you use `lstrlenW` to get the length of the ciphertext which returns it based on null-termination. Ciphertext looks random, so its bound to have bytes that are `\0` anywhere in the ciphertext. You should use your `size` value for decryption instead of overwriting it with `lstrlenW(Encrypted)`.</strike>

Comment: The code checks that `Message[i] + oglKeyTable[i%OGL_KEYTABLE_SIZE]` won't be zero, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed this, but I think I know what is now.